# Can Nigeria passport holder transit Brazil from South Africa without visa?

Tags: transit, layovers, brazil, nigerian-citizens

Please do Nigeria passport holder transiting south Africa to Brazil to connect flight to Kingston need visa?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Brazil transit visa as long as you have an onward ticket and remain in the designated transit area (for a maximum of 7 hours). However, if you want to leave the airport you need a visa unless you are from a visa exempt country.

Nigeria is not a exempt country and therefore if you want to visit the country, you will need a visa.

http://www.portalconsular.itamaraty.gov.br/vistos-para-viajar-ao-brasil#precisa
https://www.brazilevisas.com/transit-visa/